# Compression Tool (Zip/Rar) for Windows

Tags: windows, zip

I', looking for a zip/unzip tool for Windows PC.

Preferably,

- Multi-core support
- Full 256-bit encryption
- Excel and Word add-ins to compress, send and encrypt the document(optional)
- Split-view Explorer with additional ZIP features
- Access main features quickly through Windows Explorer right-click menu
- Built-in cloud support
- Use virtual drives
- Able to Support all popular compression formats (RAR, ZIP, CAB, ARJ, LZH, ACE, TAR, GZip, UUE, ISO, BZIP2, Z, and 7-Zip).

Answer (score 3):

How about https://www.7-zip.org

The downside is it lacks:

- Excel and Word add-ins to compress, send and encrypt the document(optional)
- Built-in cloud support

But i do not understand what is meant by

> Built-in cloud support

All others are supported.
See here (https://www.howtogeek.com/325304/the-best-file-extraction-and-compression-tool-for-windows/) for a small presentation with some pictures.